# MATLAB using dir to search for specific filenames?

Tags: matlab, search, directory, filenames

How can I use the dir command to look for files with certain parts? For example if I wanted all files in a directory that had 'random' in their names, how would I go about selecting only those files?

I know you can use the wildcard to look for certain strings, but is it possible to do it with variables? If name = random, then how would I look for files with 'random' in their names using just name?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is quite straightforward:

```
dir *random*
```

Quotes around random are optional.

Answer (score 0):

```
dir(['*' name '*'])
```

Also, make sure

```
name='random'
```

not

```
name=random
```